How to Group Records where Record interval is less than 15 minutes apart
I want to be able to group data by the time gap between records being less than 15 minuetes.
I have the below Query
SELECT TimeStamp
FROM Batch
WHERE Product = '1203'
AND TimeStamp BETWEEN '2024-04-17 06:00:00.000' AND '2024-04-17 15:00:00.000'
ORDER BY TimeStamp

What I would like to have something like this
SELECT Min(TimeStamp), Max(TimeStamp, Count(TimeStamp)


I would use Lag and DateDiff

What if there are three timestamps 10minutes part from each other, but 20min apart end to end? Please show sample data and expected results including edge cases.

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/PHiekGBk

WITH Gap as
  (
SELECT b.TimeStamp, Isnull(Lag(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp),TimeStamp) as PreviousTimeStamp, datediff(minute, Isnull(Lag(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp),TimeStamp),TimeStamp ) as MinutesDiff, CASE WHEN datediff(minute, Isnull(Lag(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp),TimeStamp),TimeStamp ) < 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as LessThan15MinGap
FROM Batch b
WHERE Product = '1203'
AND b.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2024-04-17 06:00:00.000' AND '2024-04-17 15:00:00.000'
)
SELECT LessThan15MinGap, Min(TimeStamp) as MinTimeStamp, Max(TimeStamp) as MaxTimeStamp, Count(*) as Count
FROM GAP 
GROUP By LessThan15MinGap

fiddle fiddle2



TimeStamp
PreviousTimeStamp
MinutesDiff
LessThan15MinGap




2024-04-17 06:00:00.000
2024-04-17 06:00:00.000
0
1


2024-04-17 06:31:00.000
2024-04-17 06:30:00.000
1
1


2024-04-17 06:10:00.000
2024-04-17 06:00:00.000
10
1


2024-04-17 06:30:00.000
2024-04-17 06:10:00.000
20
0


2024-04-17 15:00:00.000
2024-04-17 06:31:00.000
509
0






LessThan15MinGap
MinTimeStamp
MaxTimeStamp
Count




0
2024-04-17 06:30:00.000
2024-04-17 15:00:00.000
2


1
2024-04-17 06:00:00.000
2024-04-17 06:31:00.000
3



